# Views custom style

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have a field collection displayed in a view. Currently, it renders it this way:
[image]

I'd like to render all items in one green box though, not all items in a box seperately. I thought I would be able to do this using "style settings" in the view settings.

However, this doesn't seem to work. I've tried all different options, but the class I provide is NOT added in the elements and so the display doesn't change.

Why doesn't that work? Am I wrong by using style settings to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to your view by doing this:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be adding the class to the individual items...

Comment: @Bv202 did you flush the cache?

Comment: yup, I did several times (same with my browser cache)

Comment: @Bv202 not with your browser, [in drupal](http://cdn.inmotionhosting.com/support/images/stories/edu/Drupal_7/Configuration/Development/Performance/config-deve-perf-clear-cache.png)

Comment: Yes, I know what you meant :) it appears I was wrong: the class simply doesn't seem to get added...

Comment: @Bv202 you are writting the class without the dot (.) right? example: `myclass`

Comment: Hehe, yup, I am :)

Comment: try different classes?

Answer (score 0):

In your View

**Click on your Field Collection Field and scroll down to the setting "Multiple Field Settings".**

Select "Display all values in the same row". That should do the trick.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I've never seen that option. Could you tell me where exactly I can find it?

Comment: @Bv202 read the **bold** part, it says there =)

Comment: Yes, but there is no "Multiple Field Settings"..

Comment: @Bv202 I found this [Missing Multiple Field Settings](https://www.ostraining.com/support-forum/drupal-support/missing-multiple-field-settings/)

Comment: It's set on "Unlimited" :s

Comment: can you briefly explain how are you building your view? what kind of content? and how is your field collection relates to that content?

Answer (score 0):

Could you share a screenshot of your settings?
However, in the Format section i would go to settings and group my fields.
Then add a class for each row, right after Grouping setting